# Zend Framework 2 Event Manager

Tags: php, events, zend-framework2

I am learning about zf2 events and below is my code:

```
module.php

 public function init(ModuleManagerInterface $managers) {       
    $eventManager = $managers->getEventManager();
    /* $eventManager->attach('do', array($this, function ($e) {
        $event = $e->getName();
        $params = $e->getParams();
        printf(
                'Handled event "%s", with parameters %s',
                $event,
                json_encode($params)
                );
        })
    ); */

    $eventManager->attach('do', array($this, 'demoEvent') );

}
public function demoEvent(Event $e) {
    echo  ' in demo Event';
}
```

and in controller function i have triggered the event.

```
 $this->getEventManager()->trigger('do', $this, ['aman', 'deep']);
```

but call to demoEvent action is never made. Even i tried using closure as you can see above but it gives me "Invalid callback provided" Exception.

What i am doing wrong. Can someone help me in understanding Event Manager better. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is almost correct. The problem is that you are attaching the event listener "demoEvent" to the *application* event manager, rather than the *controller*'s event manager.

As the controller, assuming that it extends `AbstractActionController`, will also be capable of triggering it's own events.

You therefore need to update the way you attach the listener to ensure it is registered with the correct event manager.

There are a few options.

- Attach event listeners inside the controller factory. You can call `$controller->getEventManager()->attach();` inside the factory so when the controller is created the event listener is always attached.
- Override the `attachDefaultListeners()` defined in the `AbstractActionController` this will automatically be called when the controller is initialized by the controller manager. This provides access to the controllers event manager, just be sure to remember to call `parent::attachDefaultListeners()`.
- Lastly, you can use the "Shared Event Manager" which is really just a proxy to the target event manager (and despite its name, not an event manager). This allows you to only slightly modify the code you have written and keep event listener registration independent of the triggering context (controller).

For example.

```
class Module
{

    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $mvcEvent)
    {
        $sharedManager = $mvcEvent->getEventManager()->getSharedManager();

        $sharedManager->attach(
            'Foo\\Controller\\BarController', // Event manager 'identifier', which one we want
            'do'                    // Name of event to listen to
            [$this, 'demoEvent'],   // The event listener to trigger
            1,                      // event priority 
        );
    }

    public function demoEvent($event)
    {

    }

}
```

Comment: Tried first two approaches and it worked like charm. But since there are different Event Manager like for controller, application how one should know that he is attaching the Listener to correct Event Manager ?  Can you provide me some links or anything from where i can learn more about Event Manager. As till now not able to find any good documentation on EM. Anyways thanks for detailed answer.

Comment: Inside the event manager class is an 'identifiers' array that stores a number of names you can reference.  The implementing `__CLASS__` constant is used by default, so my answer should really read `Foo\Controller\BarController` for it to work. Check out  [`AbstractActionController::setEventManager()`](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-mvc/blob/release-2.7/src/Controller/AbstractController.php#L161) and also within the [`EventManagerAwareTrait::setEventManager()`](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/blob/release-2.6.3/src/EventManagerAwareTrait.php).